# What is the correct and efficient way for outputting json from MongoDB collections?

Tags: java, json, mongodb

below you'll see a sample related with my style of serving of a mongodb collection data, it works but I've just concatenated the strings which is no good and thus it does not seem correct to me, I've checked for it on the net but could not see anything, if anyone knows please share with me.

```
@Path("/getdata/{collectionName}/{count}")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getData(@PathParam("collectionName") String collectionName, @PathParam("count") int count) throws UnknownHostException{
    DB db = (new MongoClient("localhost")).getDB("testdb");
    DBCollection dbCollection = db.getCollection(collectionName);
    BasicDBObject basicDBObject = new BasicDBObject();
    basicDBObject.put("name", "mustafa");
    DBCursor dbCursor = dbCollection.find(basicDBObject);
    String result = "{\" "+ collectionName +" \": [";

    int i = 0;
    while(dbCursor.hasNext() && i < count){
        result += dbCursor.next() + ", ";
        i++;
    }

    result = result.substring(0,result.length()-2);
    result += "]}";
    return result;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "publish"?

Comment: outputting data as json

Comment: in a sort of REST service output or what?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize()` method to serialize your objects to JSON and return back.

Comment: String result = com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize(dbCursor); it just gives null set like this []